# Add horizontal scroll to table in MediaWIki (Pivot theme)

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, mediawiki, zurb-foundation-6, skin

I'm trying to add horizontal scroll for overflow to tables without the need to edit tables individually in MediaWiki. I installed the Pivot theme which is based on Zurb Foundation.

Here's what the table looks like right now:

[image: Table without horizontal scroll for overflow when viewed on mobile]

Example: https://wiki.d-addicts.com/Love_Story_in_Harvard

Answer (score 1):

Foundation's CSS has a wrapper class you can add to a table for it to scroll.

```
<div class="table-scroll">
  <table></table>
</div>
```

You can find the API docs here: https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/table.html#scrolling-table